# Prevent default action but don't stop the event propagating

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-propagation

I need the code to work on IE6+, just wanted to check I haven't missed out support for any browsers.

This code works and I have tested on IE7, Firefox 10, Google Chrome 17 but I don't have the other browsers to test. What I want to know if anyone else has done this and know what the code is, have I missed support for any browser with my code:

```
    if (!e) e = window.event;       
    e.returnValue = false;      
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();           
    return false;
```

Comment: What method do you use for binding event handlers? I'm asking because you want to normalize the event object inside that method, and *not* inside the event handler itself. Once normalized, just execute `e.preventDefault();` from within the event handler.

Comment: Surely e.preventDefault() simply wouldn't work because IE6 doesn't implement the method?

Comment: That's why you have to *normalize* the event object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[preventDefault()](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Event-preventDefault) is a w3c DOM Level 2 standard, so it should be implemented by all modern browsers.

IE6 is not a modern browser however, and it doesn't implement DOM Level 2 or `preventDefault()`. The alternative IE6 uses setting `event.returnValue` to `false`, as you did. Note that this will not affect event bubbling (in IE6 that would be accomplished by setting `event.cancelBubble` to true). So your code as it is should work in IE6 as well as all modern browsers to prevent the default action without stopping propagation.

But I'd restructure the code to not set any properties on the event if you don't have to:

```
if (e.preventDefault) {
    e.preventDefault();
} else {
    e.returnValue = false;
}
```